# SQL Server - transpose data conditionally

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, user-defined-functions, transpose

I have a data set as in the picture below:
[Original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSpmJ.png)

I need to build a report like the following :
[Report needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGowb.png)

Basically each person have some entries in PersonLang table. The entries represent a row for each language-skill combination plus the level.

The report should contain all languages that a person knows, order column-wise in the desc order of the score(level). The advanced comes first, then medium, etc.

I have tried so far couple of things:

1. I tried to use PIVOT but I don't know beforehand all the languages for a person and also if a person knows only 1 language it should appear in the first column
2. I tried to use window functions (Lead) partitioned by personid and ordered by language level. Here I had problems because I need a single row per language over all skills
3. I was thinking to write a table-valued function that will take the original dataset as a cursor and then convert it in the desired table. Here I have problems with inserting in the same row all the values and if a langugage appears twice with the same level I should only update the level.

I think I overthink this somehow and maybe someone with a clearer mind can point me to the right solution. What should be applied to the original data set in order to obtain the desired result ?

### SQL statements to replicate the data:

```
create table personlang(
  personid number,
  lang varchar2(20),
  langskill varchar2(20),
  lvl varchar2(20),
  score number)


 insert into personlang values (101, 'Dutch', 'Spoken', 'Advanced', 3);
 insert into personlang values (101, 'Dutch', 'Written', 'Medium', 2);
 insert into personlang values (101, 'French', 'Spoken', 'Medium', 2);
 insert into personlang values (101, 'Arabic', 'Written','Begineer',1);
 insert into personlang values (102, 'English', 'Spoken','Advanced',3);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it is sql server?? Varchar2 datatype seems like Oracle

Comment: Yes, I need a solution for SQL server, I built this data type on oracle as I did not have access to the SQL Server station at the moment. Ignore the data type. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max),@col NVARCHAR(max)

     SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',','')+'[ForeignLand'+n.LangID+'],[ForeignLand'+n.LangID+'Spoken],['+'ForeignLand'+n.LangID+'Written]'
     FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY personid ORDER BY lang)) AS LangID
       FROM personlang 
     ) n
     PRINT @col
     SELECT @sql='
     SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT l.personid,c.* FROM (
           SELECT *, DENSE_RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY pl.personid ORDER BY lang) AS LangID FROM personlang AS pl
         ) l
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(''ForeignLand''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,LangID),lang)
                           ,(''ForeignLand''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,LangID)+''Spoken'',CASE WHEN langskill=''Spoken'' THEN lvl ELSE NULL END )
                           ,(''ForeignLand''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,LangID)+''Written'',CASE WHEN langskill=''Written'' THEN lvl ELSE NULL END )
         ) c(col_title,col_value)
     )m
     PIVOT(MAX(m.col_value) FOR m.col_title IN('+@col+')) p'

     exec(@sql)
```

```
personid    ForeignLand1         ForeignLand1Spoken   ForeignLand1Written  ForeignLand2         ForeignLand2Spoken   ForeignLand2Written  ForeignLand3         ForeignLand3Spoken   ForeignLand3Written
----------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
101         Arabic               NULL                 Begineer             Dutch                Advanced             Medium               French               Medium               NULL
102         English              Advanced             NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL                 NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking dynamic SQL at some point but I wasn't able to see the entire solution.